# GetCustomAttributes inherit parameter vs AttributeUsage.Inherited

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes

Why doesn't [`GetCustomAttributes(true)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254(v=vs.110).aspx) return attributes where [`AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited = false`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)? There is nothing in the documentation that I can see that says that these two should interact. The following code outputs `0`.

```
class Program
{

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
    class NotInheritedAttribute : Attribute { }

    [NotInherited]
    class A { }

    class B : A { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var attCount = typeof(B).GetCustomAttributes(true).Count();
        Console.WriteLine(attCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: `typeof(B).GetCustomAttributes(true)` will returns **all** attributes of `B` including inherite-**able** (`false` as parameter will simply filter ones from base classes). From other hand `Inherited = false` attribute on `A` is **not** added to `B`, so it can not be found/returned.

Comment: @Sinatr That question is regarding attributes on properties which is a different matter. Your comment is correct, I was assuming that `GetCustomAttributes` would look through the base classes, it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

[`Type.GetCustomAttributes()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/CustomAttributeExtensions.cs,61) is an extension method that calls [Attribute.GetCustomAttributes()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/attribute.cs,480) which in turn calls `GetCustomAttributes` with the parameter `inherit` set to `true`. So by default, you are already inheriting when using `GetCustomAttributes()`.

So the only difference is between `GetCustomAttributes()` and `GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false)`. The latter will *disable* inheritance for inheritable attributes while the former will just pass those that are inheritable through.

You cannot force attributes that are themselves non-inheritable to be inheritable.

See the following example for a quick summary:

```
void Main()
{
    typeof(A).GetCustomAttributes().Dump(); // both
    typeof(A).GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false).Dump(); // both

    typeof(B).GetCustomAttributes().Dump(); // inheritable
    typeof(B).GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false).Dump(); // none because inheritance is prevented

    typeof(C).GetCustomAttributes().Dump(); // both
    typeof(C).GetCustomAttributes(inherit: false).Dump(); // both because C comes with its own copies
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true)]
public class InheritableExampleAttribute : Attribute { }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
public class NonInheritableExampleAttribute : Attribute { }

[InheritableExample]
[NonInheritableExample]
public class A { }

public class B : A { }

[InheritableExample]
[NonInheritableExample]
public class C : A { }
```

Comment: So the answer to my question is that `GetCustomAttributes()` doesn't iterate through base classes, it just looks at the current class and can distinguish between inherited and non-inherited attributes?

Comment: That is correct, yeah. The `AttributeUsage` attribute decides which attributees are carried over, but the `GetCustomAttributes` does only look at one type, it does not walk up the dependency tree.